# Joomla 1.7 loadObjectList returns always null

Tags: php, database, joomla1.7

I am using custom php code in a Joomla 1.7 in order to fetch some articles from the db.
Although the sql query works on the mysql level, it returns null in the joomla script.

```
$query = " SELECT id, title "              
." FROM #__content "
." WHERE catid=".$categoyID." AND state > 0 AND created BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 15 YEAR AND SYSDATE()"
."";

$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$db->setQuery( $query );     

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
//$articles = $db->loadObjectList();
// Get list items

if ($rows!=null)
{
    $i=0;
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {              
        echo '<br>'.$row->id;
        echo '<br>'.$row->title;

        $i++;
    }   

}
else echo "<br> NULL results from ".$query;
```

I am always get a NULL results. Propably its something worng with my Joomla config but what ?

Comment: found that I get the following error message:  `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQL=SELECT id, title FROM hj7mr_content WHERE catid=9 AND state > 0 AND created BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 15 YEAR AND SYSDATE()`

Comment: So now the question is on how I should handle the `$db = JFactory::getDBO();`  connections

Comment: Issue SOLVED! A stored procedure in the MySqL caused this mess. So I wrote a method to clear up the shared memory: `function clearStoredResults($db) {
 //$link = $this->db->getConnection();
 $link = $db->getConnection();
 while ($link->more_results()) {
  $link->next_result();
  if ($result = $link->store_result()) {    
   $result->free();
  }
 }
}`